# Beltrami equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The second order linear PDE

$a(x,y)u_{xx}+ 2b(x,y)u_{xy}+c(x,y)u_{yy}= 0$

was transformed by introducing new independent variable $ξ=φ(x,y)$ and $η=ψ(x,y)$, transforming the PDE to the form

$A(ξ,η)u_{ξξ}+ 2B(ξ,η)u_{ξη}+C(ξ,η)u_{ηη}= 0$

with

$A=a\phi_x^2 + 2b\phi_x\phi_y+c\phi_y^2$

$B=a\phi_x\psi_x+b(\phi_x\psi_y+\phi_y\psi_x)+c\phi_y\psi_y$

$C=a\psi_x^2+2b\psi_x\psi_y+c\psi_y^2$

Assume we are in the elliptic case.
Show that  in  this  case  we  can  obtain  the  situation $A=C$ and $B=0$ in case that $ψ$ and $φ$ are solutions of

$\phi_x=\frac{bψ_x+c\psi_y}{\sqrt{ac−b^2}},\;\;\;\phi_y=−\frac{aψ_x+b\psi_y}{\sqrt{ac−b^2}}$

and $ψ$ is a solution of the Beltrami equation:

$\left(\frac{aψ_x+b\psi_y}{\sqrt{ac−b^2}}\right)_x+ \left(\frac{bψ_x+c\psi_y}{\sqrt{ac−b^2}}\right)_y= 0$.

I've tried to calculate $A-C=0$ and $B=0$ and set them even. But I'm stuck at

$\frac{\phi_x+i\psi_x}{\phi_y+i\psi_y} = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}$.

Can you guys please help me? :)